# How to scroll up in ubuntu server terminal?

Tags: command-line, server, scrolling, mouse-scroll

To scroll up and down (by mouse) I found this advise

> Go the terminal program, and make sure
> Edit/Profile Preferences/Scrolling/Scrollback/Unlimited
> is checked

But window is as shown below:

[image]

How to scroll up and down correctly (with mouse)? I tried to `shift + pg up`, but it doesn't help me.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @OwenHines 16.04 xenial

Answer (score 1):

There's a Limit scrollback to option in Menu bar -> Edit -> Profile Preferences -> Scrolling. Uncheck the checkbox for unlimited scrollbar.

Comment: It hasn't helped me.

Comment: Did anything change?

Comment: nope =( Everything is the same.

Comment: Did you restart the terminal window/make a new window? Also, make sure you *unchecked* the checkbox.

Comment: OP wants to use mouse for scrolling. As far as i know, it's not supported. Only shift+pgup work s

Comment: @Serg okay, so basically what I answered is as close as he can get/use shift+pgup?

Comment: @owenHines technically yes. That shortcut works in tty and graphical terminal. OP can click on the scroll bar and drag, but he wants mouse wheel, as far as i understand - that doesn't work. Some terminals might have support for it though, but i don't recall gnome-terminal which is default ever having such feature